# How to handle if app is opened from URL in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method?

Tags: ios, objective-c

When iOS application is opened from some URL `AppDelegates's` methods are called in such a sequence:

```
1. - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

2. - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
```

How to know in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method if application was opened from URL or not. May be there are some launching options which I miss?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can inspect `launchOptions` passed to `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`.

Look for section `Launch Options Keys` in reference [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html), specifically `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey`

Comment: Specifically the presence of the `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey` key

Answer (score 6):

If your app has been launch from a URL You will find a

```
UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey
```

in the `launchOptions` Dictionary of - `(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

On a related note the `handleOpenURL:` method is deprecated, you should use:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually answers about `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey` are correct but not complete. In case if user for example taps Universal Link in Messages app and is redirected into your app, you receive these launch options instead of `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey`:

```
[
    UIApplicationLaunchOptionsSourceApplicationKey: com.apple.MobileSMS,
    UIApplicationLaunchOptionsUserActivityDictionaryKey: [
         UIApplicationLaunchOptionsUserActivityKey: <NSUserActivity>,
         UIApplicationLaunchOptionsUserActivityTypeKey: NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb
    ]
]
```

So, to check if user landed into the app from URL you need this code in this case:

```
let isFromUrl = ((launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.userActivityDictionary] as? NSDictionary)?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.userActivityType] as? String == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb)
```

and if the check passes, handle incoming URL in:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    if userActivity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb {
        let url = userActivity.webpageURL
        // do your stuff ...
    }
return false
}
```

Comment: This answer should be higher up. Even the documentation fails to clearly specify this.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should implement `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`
Check the URL. It should return YES if you can open it or NO if you can't.

And then implement `application:handleOpenURL:`
Open the URL. It should return YES if successful or NO.